# How to match all words starting with a certain sequence of letters in a for loop? (Python)

Tags: python, text, string-matching, word-count

I have a dictionary with some personality traits and related adjectives:

```
personality={'sincerity': [ "tru", "honest"],'excitement': ['excit', 'fizzy']}
```

(note this is much longer)

As well I have a dictionary with lists of words extracted from tweets:

```
prova={"brand1": ["true", "truth", "thrutfull", "orange", "friend", "meaning"], "brand2": ["truth", "exiting", "excited", "lama", "lambo", "blade"]}
```

I want to match one string in the personality dictionary with all the strings containing that character in the prova dictionary: the string "tru" in personality[sincerity] should match "true", "truth", "truthful" in prova[brand1] and "truth" in prova[brand2].

As i have many brands, I would like to do so through a for loop. any suggestion?

Comment: Small tip: it is better to not mix single and double quotes when defining strings. [Python's style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes) invite us to pick one and stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is what you describe in your comment to @Wasif Hasan's answer, which is different from what you have in your problem description, you can try:

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> import re
>>>
>>> personality = {
...     "sincerity": ["tru", "honest"],
...     "excitement": ["excit", "fizzy"]}
>>> prova = {
...     "brand1": ["true", "truth", "thrutfull", "orange", "friend", "meaning"], 
...     "brand2": ["truth", "exiting", "excited", "lama", "lambo", "blade"]}
>>>
>>> patterns = {k:re.compile(f"\s?({'|'.join(v)})") for k,v in personality.items()}
>>> results = defaultdict(dict)
>>>
>>> for k1, v1 in prova.items():
...     for k2, v2 in patterns.items():
...         results[k1][k2] = len(v2.findall(' '.join(v1)))
... 
>>> results
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'brand1': {'sincerity': 2, 'excitement': 0}, 'brand2': {'sincerity': 1, 'excitement': 1}})
>>> results['brand1']
{'sincerity': 2, 'excitement': 0}
```

The code above first creates a `dict` of regular expression objects (see `patterns = ...`). The `dict` has the same keys as `personality` and the values are objects that correspond to patterns generated by the values in `personality`. For example, the pattern for `sincerity` is `"\s?(tru|honest)"`. The pattern is constructed so that I can later search for `tru` or `honest` following no or one whitespaces. I use the patterns to search for matches in the values for each brand in `prova`. For counting occurances, I construct a string from the values (for example for `brand1` `["true", "truth", "thrutfull", "orange", "friend", "meaning"]` becomes `"true truth thrutfull orange friend meaning"`) and use `len(findall)` to find the number of matches.

Notes:

1. I assume that the `list`s associated with each brand in `prova` have no duplicates (or that if they have duplicates, you are interested in counting multiple times a word that appears multiple times). If this is not the case, you will need to update `' '.join(v1)` using `set()` to eliminate duplicates.
2. I also assume that the strings in `personality` are how you expect the words in `prova` to begin. If instead, you are looking for matches everywhere, you will need to update `re.compile...` by, say, removing `\s?`.
3. In your description you have a typo, i.e., "thrutfull". That is why even though you expect *"tru" in personality[sincerity] to match "true", "truth", "truthful" in prova[brand1]* what you see happening above is that there are 2 matches (instead of 3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop like this:

```
personality={'sincerity': [ "tru", "honest"],'excitement': ['excit', 'fizzy']} 

prova={"brand1": ["true", "truth", "truthfull", "orange", "friend", "meaning"], "brand2": ["truth", "exiting", "excited", "lama", "lambo", "blade"]} 

d = []
for x in personality.values():
  for y in prova.values():
    for z in y:
      for n in x:
        if n in z: 
          d.append(z)
print(d)
```

But three cheers for list comprehension!!

```
d = [z for x in personality.values() for y in prova.values() for z in y for n in x if n in z]
print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I would like to have at the end would be something like:   brand 1 = {sincerity: 1234, excitement: 5678, ... } for all the brands, where the number are the number of times words inside personality[sincerity] and personality[excitement] appears into prova[brand1].